# Magento Database Maintenance

Tags: database, magento-1, log

I have the Magento backend set to autoclean logs, for testing purposes I timed it to generate instantly and had 0 days for saving logs.

That didn't clean the logs. I ran:

```
php -f shell/log.php clean
```

This only truncated a small bit of the logs, but still left them as they used to be.

```
log_customer
log_quote
log_summary
log_summary_type
log_url
log_url_info
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_visitor_online
report_viewed_product_index
report_compared_product_index
report_event
```

Comment: This questions has already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638361/clearing-magento-log-data

Answer (score 2):

Apart from shell log clean up, you can also try:

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
TRUNCATE catalog_compare_item;
```

In the Magento Admin, go to

> System > Configuration

.
    In the left menu under

> Advanced

click on System.

> Under “Log Cleaning”, change “Enable Log Cleaning” to YES and
>   configure the Save Log for 15 days:
>       Click “Save Config”.

Comment: I assume `php log.php clean` will clean the logs within these tables. Where are the logs saved and do they auto clean after "15" days?